# Polymer.dart data-binding: updating model values without updating view

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have an element like this:

```html
<polymer-element name="content-editable" attributes="value">
  <template>
    <div contenteditable="true" on-input="{{updateValue}} id="#editor">{{value}}</div>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="content_editable.dart"></script>
</polymer>
```

With codebehind like this:

```dart
@CustomTag('content-editable')
class ContentEditable {
  @published String value;
  ContentEditable.created(); : super.created();

  // This event handler is called every time the content of #editor changes.
  void updateValue(event, detail, sender) {
    // This code will update [value] -- which will then overwrite the contents of #editor!
    // That will reset the cursor position and other undesired behaviors.
    value = sender.text
  }
}
```

In AngularDart they have a "model" mechanism. The code to utilize it is would look like this:

```dart
Model model;
void updateValue(event, detail, sender) {
  // This code tells everyone watching for changes on Model.value that its value has changed,
  // but it will NOT cause the template to re-render the value for #editor.
  model.valueView = sender.text;
}
```

How can I set ContentEditable.value without causing Polymer to immediately reset the contents of #editor?

Answer (score 1):

Here is *a* solution I hacked-up. Given its awkwardness and reliance on an experimental Polymer feature, I'm hoping its not "the" solution:

HTML:

```html
<polymer-element name="content-editable" attributes="value">
  <template>
    <div contenteditable="true" on-input="{{updateValue}} id="#editor">
      <!-- use Polymer's _experimental_ one time binding syntax -->
      [[value]]
    </div>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="content_editable.dart"></script>
</polymer>
```

Code behind:

```dart
@CustomTag('content-editable')
class ContentEditable {
  @published String value;
  ContentEditable.created(); : super.created();

  void attached() {
    var editor = $['editor'];
    // v == List<PropertyChangeRecord>
    // expand the list so that where is called once per PropertyChangeRecord
    // this comment exists only for StackOverflow readers!
    this.changes.expand((v) => v).where((pcr) => pcr.name == #value).listen((pcr) {
      // An outside source updated value; naively repopulate editor content.
      if (editor.text != pcr.newValue) { editor.text = pcr.newValue; }
    });
  }

  void updateValue(event, detail, sender) {
    value = sender.text
  }
}
```

This is a poor solution because you have to iterate through the entire list of changes every time the 'input' event is fired in order to see what the origin of the event was. You can ignore internal change events (you did it, after all) but you can't ignore external change events (document was updated remotely, etc). An ideal solution involves implicitly ignoring internal events so that you don't spend time iterating through the change event stream.